# Chrome extension not waiting for DOM to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access any element on YouTube from a content script.

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
      "js": ["content/content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

However, when logging the element, I sometimes get null and sometimes the element is logged.

**content.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', afterDOMLoaded)

function afterDOMLoaded() {
    const element = document.getElementById('top')
    console.log(element)
}
```

It works when using setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    const element = document.getElementById('top')
    console.log(element)
}, 3000)
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37319267/6193522) that this is because the element is being added later dynamically, by the page's javascript, and the only way to solve this is by using a MutationObserver/[mutation-summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary). This seems like a lot of hassle for just accessing an element. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: You could check if an element has appeared in the DOM using `setInterval` but I doubt that it's a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

By Loading asynchronously we will get the solution run at "document_idle".
In the case of "document_idle", the browser chooses a time to inject scripts between "document_end" and immediately after the window.onload event fires.

Update manifest.json

`"content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "matches": [
        "*://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
 ]`

In Content script, get the document ready state and do with asynchronous way.

```
HTMLDocument.prototype.ready = new Promise(function (resolve) {
if (document.readyState != "loading")
    return resolve();
else
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        return resolve();
    });
});

document.ready.then(function () {
    const element = document.getElementById('top')
    console.log(element)
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Probably because the page loads the elements dynamically/async? So the element that I want to access is not loaded when the events fire? (document.readyState and "DOMContentLoaded")

Comment: @Junker, I have tried it it work, I did it by having the background script injecting the js page. like this ```  if ('complete' !== changeInfo.status) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'board.js' }, () =>
      console.log('complete')
    )
  }```

Answer (score 0):

Try DOMSubtreeModified, which fires each time DOM is modified:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
        if(document.getElementById("my_element")) {
                //element is added
        }
});
```